# Cannot find -l<library in Eclipse c++

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am attempting to use the rapidxml C++ library in Eclipse C++. The following error is repeatedly showing-

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.4/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrapidxml
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.4/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrapidxml_print
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.4/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrapidxml_utils
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.4/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrapidxml_iterators
```

The path is already set-up 
[image]

The libraries too
[image]

so what's going on? What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rapidxml consists only of .hpp. It does not have any .a .so or .dll files to add as a library. It can simply be included as headers without the extra effort.